# npm ERR! Cannot read property 'extraneous' of undefined

Tags: node.js

This error occurs when I use npm to install
npm i jquery

```
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'extraneous' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 30):

Try removing your package-lock.json:
`rm -rf package-lock.json`

Comment: as an aside, I'm not sure `-rf` is needed here.

Answer (score 6):

You can try deleting the node_modules folder in addition to removing the package-lock.json
Worked for me

Comment: Just deleting the `node_modules` folder worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command. Hopefully, it would solve the problem by removing unnecessary packages.

```
npm prune
```

Answer (score -1):

`git checkout master package-lock.json`

Erasing the lock file is not such a great idea.

Comment: the lock file is generated when you run an install, deleting it is fine